# Calling DatePicker multiple times using single listener

Tags: android, datepicker

I have for date and time fields in same form. So I need to four date and time pickers for those fields. Currently I am able to get that but all the fields are showing same time and date and all the fields are getting set when I select the time and date from the first picker.

I have used several methods, some being checking view id of each field, giving id's to dialogs and using switch in onCreateDialog method etc.. But nothing is working for me. Please suggest me how can I achieve this.

My DatePicker code:

```
 public void showDatePicker() {
        DatePickerFragment date1 = new DatePickerFragment();
    /**
     * Set Up Current Date Into dialog
     */
    Calendar calender = Calendar.getInstance();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("year", calender.get(Calendar.YEAR));
    args.putInt("month", calender.get(Calendar.MONTH));
    args.putInt("day", calender.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    date1.setArguments(args);

    /**
     * Set Call back to capture selected date
     */
    date1.setCallBack(ondate);
    date1.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "Date Picker");



}




    DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener ondate =  new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                          int dayOfMonth) {




            date.setText(String.valueOf(dayOfMonth) + "-" + String.valueOf(monthOfYear + 1)
                    + "-" + String.valueOf(year));

            dateValue = date.getText().toString();

            est_compDate.setText(String.valueOf(dayOfMonth) + "-" + String.valueOf(monthOfYear + 1)
                    + "-" + String.valueOf(year));

            estValue = est_compDate.getText().toString();


            act_compDate.setText(String.valueOf(dayOfMonth) + "-" + String.valueOf(monthOfYear + 1)
                    + "-" + String.valueOf(year));

            actValue = act_compDate.getText().toString();



            notify_date.setText(String.valueOf(dayOfMonth) + "-" + String.valueOf(monthOfYear + 1)
                    + "-" + String.valueOf(year));

            notifyValue = notify_date.getText().toString();



    }
};
```

My DatePickerFragment code:

```
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment {
    DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener ondateSet;

public DatePickerFragment() {
}
public void setCallBack(DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener ondate) {

    ondateSet = ondate;

}



private int year, month, day;


@Override
public void setArguments(Bundle args) {
    super.setArguments(args);
    year = args.getInt("year");
    month = args.getInt("month");
    day = args.getInt("day");
}

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), ondateSet, year, month, day);


}
```

}

So when I select the time and date picker for date.setText line all the other three are getting set at a time.

I am calling picker method using an onClick method:

public void datePicker(View view) {

```
    showDatePicker();

}
```

Please let me know what can be done. If you need more information please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update:
make an interface in your DialogFragment and put an abstract method in it which will hold your date in string in its argument. then implement this interface in your main activity and overide DateInString(String) method in your activity which will give you selected date in your activity.then you can show it where you want.
i am showing you a working code where i have to set date in two places you can use it many time by modifying DateInString(String) overrided method in your activity...

DialogFragment:

```
public class Date extends android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    DatePickerData datePickerData ;
    String date = null;
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        byte month = (byte)cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        byte day = (byte ) cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(),this,year,month,day);
    }


    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int selectedYear, int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.set(selectedYear,selectedMonth,selectedDay);
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
      date = dateFormat.format(cal.getTime());
        passDate(date);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        datePickerData = (DatePickerData)activity;
    }

    public void passDate(String date){
    datePickerData.DateInString(date);   
    public interface DatePickerData{
        public void DateInString(String date);
    }
}
```

and your Activity:

```
public class ActMarkAttendance extends FragmentActivity implements Date.DatePickerData{
private boolean isStartDate = false;
private TextView startDateTextView;
    private TextView endDateTextView;
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_act_view_attendance);
        startDateTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.startDateTextView_attView);
        endDateTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.endDateTextView_attView);
startDateTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
            isStartDate = true;                
            showDateFragment();                  
            }
        });

        endDateTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                isStartDate = false;
               showDateFragment();                    
            }
        });
}
private void showDateFragment(){
        Date dateFragment = new Date();
        dateFragment.show(fm,General.NOTHING);
    }
@Override
    public void DateInString(String date) {
    if (isStartDate)
        startDateViewer.setText(date);
    else
        endDateViewer.setText(date);

    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry. Didn't understand the second part. "Set date to string". Can  you please elaborate.

Comment: Not getting. i am able to display date picker in my application. I have 4 fields which use date picker in a form. i need to set different dates on each how can I do that?

Comment: When you want to set date in different places then you have to open dialog many times which means you have to create instance of dialogFragment at every place where you want ti select date

Comment: Yes I tried that. I was getting a blank white box and not picker at that time. Will check and let you know.

Comment: Will Implement this and will tell you.

Comment: I am trying this, I am not able to implement the OnClickListner as you have done. not understanding why. Can you please tell me?

Comment: Also for ICommParent its is showing no libraries are available

Comment: Remove ICommParent and then check

Comment: added OnClickListeners. ok. where have you declared fragment manager fm? sorry got it.

Comment: Yes Thanks a lot. Is isStartDate just variables? is there any significance for using them? Final clarification Please....

Comment: startDateViewer and endDateViewer, even are those textViews?

Comment: This is working exactly for two dialogs. I need four, i am trying to modify the interface method DateInString but it is not working what can be done. Can you please tell me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72318/discussion-between-adnan-ali-and-kesh1234).